# Updating value does not rerender (Without using useState)

Tags: react-native, react-hooks

I was recently asked this question in interview, which I am not able to answer it.

My(Interviewer's) question is:

Consider this code snippet, with two buttons and a text

```js
import { Text, StyleSheet, View, Button } from 'react-native';

let a = 0;

const incrementA = () => {
  console.log(`a => ${a}`);
  a += 1;
  console.log(`a = ${a}`);
};

export default function App() {
  let b = 0;

  const incrementB = () => {
    console.log(`b => ${b}`);
    b += 1;
    console.log(`b = ${b}`);
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View>
        <Text>{a}</Text>
        <Button title="Increment a" onPress={incrementA} />
      </View>
      <View>
        <Text>{b}</Text>
        <Button title="Increment b" onPress={incrementB} />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
});
```

What I was asked is that, on click of any buttons, what will be the output on the screen, On click of "Increment a" button, will it update the a's value on screen, same for the "Increment b" button.

After giving wrong answers he told me that, value of "a" will rerender, but value of b will not. and he also gave me example of useState which returns an array containing two values first the value itself and the second the setter function to update this value, here the setter function is called from the component but is present outside of the component, so his conclusion was that, if we update the value outside of the component then it will rerender, otherwise it will not.

I am not able to create the same with the snack provided below and can someone please explain this complete scenario.

Here is the snack I created to test it: https://snack.expo.dev/@jdarshan1210/gnarly-red-french-fries

Answer (score 0):

Well, looks like either you missed something, or the interviewer was confused. Since neither `a` nor `b` are state, updating any of them will not cause a rerender.

Now, if `b` was a state, updating it with the setter function will cause a rerender. I suspect this was the actual question, The catch here is that the displayed value of `a` will also be updated to the current value whenever the component rerenders.

Comment: Well, I haven't missed anything, and the interviewer was also confident about this question, and why these values can't be rerender when we use them with let?

Comment: because when you change the value with the state setter, react knows that the state is changing and it needs to rerender the component. when you just change a variable, react doesn't track it's changes as it's not a state, and doesn't know that it needs to rerender

Comment: it's likely that the interviewer was just confidentially incorrect lol